# Debugging Windows Kernel from Linux

Tags: windbg, virtual-machine, windows-kernel

I used to debug the Windows Kernel using **VirtualKD**, **WinDBG** and a single Virtual Machine.

Recently I got a Linux machine, and now I wonder- What's the easiest way to debug the Windows Kernel when your host is unable to run **VirtualKD/WinDBG***?

I assume the solution will require two Virtual Machines, but I rather have two instances hosted on my actual machine rather than having an instance residing inside another virtual instance...

Is there anyway to make that work?

Thanks in advance!

*Wine is the last resort for stability reasons...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved! Basically, I ended up using **two** (VirtualBox) **VMs** emulating a **Serial connection** (null-modem cable) over a **Unix domain socket** (on the host). For more info, read below:

Hardware setup*:

- Debuggee:

  - Ensure the machine is turned off and edit **Serial Ports** settings.
  - Enable **Port 1**, and assign values as follows: Port Number: **COM1**, Port Mode: **Host Pipe**, Create Pipe: **Unchecked** (client), Port/File Path: **/tmp/win_link**.
- Debugger:

  - Same as above (using the same path), only this time Create Pipe should be **Checked** (server).

Debugger setup:

- Run WinDBG and press Ctrl+K to invoke **Kernel Debugging**.
- in **COM**, enter: Baudrate: 115200, Port: COM1, Resets: 0 and verify that **Pipe** and Reconnect are **unchecked** (important).
- You'll be presented with the following output: `Opened \\\\.\com1 Waiting to reconnect...`

Debuggee setup:

- Run **bootcfg /debug on /port com1 /baud 115200 /id 1**. To verify, run **bootcfg**.**
- Reboot.
- Quite early during the booting stage, WinDBG on the other machine should detect the debuggee is running.

*Assuming VirtualBox is used. VMWare/KVM users will probably be able to achieve the same results following similar steps. Also, for more info refer to the [VirtualBox docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#serialports).

**Assuming guests are Windows XP. Later versions include bcdedit, which may be used as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Your configuration seems perfect but regardless of what configuration I'm using, I can't see the serial ports on both my windows vms. Have you ever had such an issue?

Answer (score 2):

For QEMU\KVM follow those instructions:
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/GuestDebugging

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful but applies to Windows XP machines. You can refer to the following link if you need to configure 2 Windows7-based virtual machines on a Linux host: http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Category:Digital-Forensics/Computer-Forensics/Debugger/Kernel

Answer (score -1):

Another option nowadays is to enable local kernel debugging. This comes with some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/performing-local-kernel-debugging), however it will enable you to access kernel data while just using **one** VM.

This approach only works on Windows 8.0 and Windows Server 2012 and later.

Follow these steps:

1. Open a Command Prompt window as Administrator.
2. Enter `bcdedit /debug on`
3. If the computer is not already configured as the target of a debug transport, enter `bcdedit /dbgsettings local`
4. Reboot the computer.

Once the system is rebooted, you can execute `WinDBG` as `Administrator`, press `ctrl+k` or go to `File -> Attach to kernel -> Local` and press OK.

[image: Attach to Kernel Option]

At that point, you will be able to execute kernel-only commands and access kernel structures:

[image]

Tested under Windows 10 and with the new WinDBG version (preview).

Reference: [Setting Up Local Kernel Debugging of a Single Computer Manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/performing-local-kernel-debugging)

Comment: This is not a full debugging setup.